# Find JavaScript handler connected to a button's click event

Tags: javascript, html, events

During some code investigating, I found a html submit button like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Create new aicraft</button>
```

I know somewhere there is javascript code that handeles the button `click` event. How can I find that javascript code?

Comment: In Chrome, right click on the button and go to Inspect Element. Look at the Event Listeners tab

Comment: I was there and still didn't find my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Firefox:

1. <kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Find the line you want to inspect
3. Click on the small **ev** button at the end of the line (if there is nothing then no JavaScript is linked)
4. See what is linked to it

In Chrome:

1. <kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Click on the line you want to inspect
3. Click on the `"Event Listeners"` Tab (where you see the styles by default)
4. There you can see the linked events

In Edge:

1. <kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Click on the DOM Explorer tab
3. Click on the line you want to inspect
4. Click on the `"Events"` Tab (where you see the styles by default)
5. There you can see the linked events